# Upload data to Firebase database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, upload

On trying to upload data to the firebase realtime database error comes.
After filling the form data when the save button is pressed.The uploadPic function is called that upload the text from textfield to the firebase, the error message comes on the console of Android Studio.

The screenshot of the error is in the link below.
[image]

Code is also mentioned below,
The uploadPic function is at line 72

Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/dashboard.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController nameController;
  TextEditingController phoneController;
  TextEditingController emailController;
  TextEditingController addressController;
  var profileImage =
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/udhari-book.appspot.com/o/DefaultImage.png?alt=media&token=06bddd3e-7f11-476b-a982-dfb21096f9c7';
  File _image;
  String fileName;
  static var userId;
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  DatabaseReference DBRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _auth.currentUser().then((curUser) {


        userId = curUser.uid;
        print('Current user id:' + userId);
        DBRef.child(curUser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot user) {
          if (user != null) {
            setState(() {
            //Provide the initial value of the user in the text field
              phoneController = TextEditingController(text: curUser.phoneNumber);
            profileImage = user.value['ProfileImage'];
            nameController = TextEditingController(text: user.value['Name']);
            emailController = TextEditingController(text: user.value['Email']);
            addressController =TextEditingController(text: user.value['Address']);
            });
          }

      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future getImage() async {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      _image = image;
      fileName = phoneController.text;
      StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Images/$fileName');
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
      StorageTaskSnapshot imgSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
      if (imgSnapshot.error == null) {
        profileImage = await imgSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        }
      setState(() {
        print('Image uploaded successfully');
      });
    }

    Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {

        print('The user name is: '+nameController.text);
        DBRef.child(userId).set({
          'User Id': userId,
         'Name': nameController.text,
          'Mobile': fileName,
          'Email':emailController.text,
          'Address': addressController.text,
          'ProfileImage': profileImage,
        });
        setState(() {
          print('Data uploaded Successfully');
          //DashboardPage(userName: nameController.text,imgUrl: imgUrl,);
        });
      }


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('User Profile'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //Profile Image widget
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 70,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 120.0,
                            width: 120.0,
                            child: _image != null
                                ? Image.file(_image, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                : Image.network(
                                    profileImage,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Camera Icon Widget
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                      child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                          onPressed: () {
                            getImage();
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

               //Name TextField
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    validator: (input) {
                      if (input.isEmpty) return 'Please enter Name';
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0,horizontal: 20.0),
                        labelText: 'Full Name',
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)))),
                  ),
                ),


                //Mobile Text Field
                Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 40.0,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: phoneController,
                        enabled: false,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0,horizontal: 20.0),
                            labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)))),
                      ),
                    )),


                //Email Text Field
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    validator: (input) {
                      if (input.isNotEmpty && input.contains('@') == false)
                        return 'Please enter correct Email Id';
                      else if (input.isEmpty) return 'Please enter Email Id';
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0,horizontal: 20.0),
                        labelText: 'Email Id',
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)))),
                  ),
                ),
                //Address Text Field
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 30.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    maxLines: 3,
                    maxLengthEnforced: true,
                    controller: addressController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Address (Optional)',
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)))),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    //Save Button
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 130.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              uploadPic(context);
                            } else
                              setState(() {});
                          },
                          elevation: 4.0,
                          splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                          child: Text(
                            'Save',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 22.0,
                                fontFamily: 'Exo2'),
                          ),
                        )),

                    //Cancel Button
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 130.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          elevation: 4.0,
                          splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                          child: Text(
                            'Cancel',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 22.0,
                                fontFamily: 'Exo2'),
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like one of the variable you use in `uploadPic` is `null`. I recommend check the log output or running in a debugger to check which variable that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace this :**

```
TextEditingController nameController;
TextEditingController phoneController;
TextEditingController emailController;
TextEditingController addressController;
```

**With this:**

```
TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
```

**And also replace this**

```
onPressed: () {
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
uploadPic(context);
}
else
setState(() {});
},
```

**with this:**

```
OnPressed: () {
setState(() {
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
uploadPic(context);
} //else
});

                      },
```